# Error On Null Pointer But Still Unsolved on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database

i am a newbie for Android Programming.
Here i have some problem when i want to make an activity (call Category_Setting) that showing list view, but when i switch from main activity to Category_Setting the error report in Android Studio gimme some error like this

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow/com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.CategorySetting}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

I have googling for it, asking some friend, but still i even don't know what is my error for.
Please somebody answer my question with simple understanding words.
Thank You..

NB. here is my code for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private static Button BtnINewTrans;
private static Button BtnIViewCash;
private static Button BtnIAddCateg;
Spinner my_Spinner;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

//ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    my_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    select_spinner_Category();
    onButtonClickButtonListener();



}

/*ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
my_array = getTableValues();*/


/*ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, my_array);
My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);*/

public void select_spinner_Category () {
    my_Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    DatabaseHelper dbH = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> listCategory = dbH.getAllCategory();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCategory);

    adapterCategory
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    my_Spinner.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id){
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected "+label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

    /*ArrayList<String> arrayCategory;
    arrayCategory = dbHelper.getAllCategory();
    selectCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    ArrayAdapter adapterCategory  = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayCategory);
   // adapterCategory = new ArrayList<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.id.spnCategSelect, AllCategoryList);
    adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    selectCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
    selectCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}*/


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}


public void onButtonClickButtonListener(){
    BtnINewTrans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewTrans);
    BtnINewTrans.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentNewTrans = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.NewTransaction");
                    startActivity(intentNewTrans);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIViewCash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewCashflow);
    BtnIViewCash.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentViewCash = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.ViewCashflow");
                    startActivity(intentViewCash);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIAddCateg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddCateg);
    BtnIAddCateg.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentAddCateg = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.CategorySetting");
                    startActivity(intentAddCateg);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this is Category_Setting.java (where i get this error)

```
public class CategorySetting extends Activity {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CursorAdapter currAdapter;
private static Button BtnIAddCateg;
private static Button BtnICancelCateg;
private static final String TAG = CategorySetting.class.getSimpleName();
DatabaseHelper dBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (this);
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onButtonClickButtonListener();
    //reload();
}



public void reload(){
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCateg);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                                        }
                                    }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category_setting, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClickButtonListener(){

    BtnIAddCateg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewCateg);
    BtnIAddCateg.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentAddCateg = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.AddCategory");
                    startActivity(intentAddCateg);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnICancelCateg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCateg);
    BtnICancelCateg.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Post the error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this method in Category_Setting.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onButtonClickButtonListener();
    //reload();
}
```

you forgot to load the layout. You should add some code like you used in the MainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Right now, the layout is not loaded at all, so

```
BtnINewTrans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewTrans);
```

will return `null`.